# I wish to change the texture of the overlay in a modal dialog in the Jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the Jquery UI,

I am using a modal dialog which is working fine, but give a stripped overlay when it is set.

In the Jquery themeroller, I see options for other textures, but I can't figure out how to use them.

Does anybody know?

```
$('#send_message_form').dialog({ minWidth: 400, 
                                 modal: true, 
                                 overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'} });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the themeroller options during theme creation, just choose the texture you want. The selected texture will be the overlay of the modal dialog.

If you want to change it manually, change the url portion of the background attribute of the CSS class .ui-widget-overlay, which should be in the jquery-ui-.custom.css file.

Comment: Thank you... I'm loading the jquery ui css file from ajax.googleapis.com so I can't change it directly. do you know what the syntax would be if I wanted to point it to an image from within the overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'} bracket?

Comment: I don't believe such an option exists, so you'd want to change the css retrieved from the external source. I'd look at trying to extend the .ui-widget-overlay class after it's loaded. Check out jQuery's [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) API. i.e. $('#send_message_form').dialog(...) and then something like $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');